# How to save Docker image writable

Tags: docker, docker-image, image-size, writable, docker-layer

I found out that docker image is read-only.
Is there a way to save the image writable?

The reason why I post this question is because I want to modify the original image.
Delete or Update from the base image inside container.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Docker images and containers, one of the basic features is committing changes to a Docker image. When you commit to changes, you essentially create a new image with an additional layer that modifies the base image layer.

Create a new image by committing the changes using the following syntax:

```
sudo docker commit [CONTAINER_ID] [new_image_name]
```

I hope this answer help you.

Comment: While this is technically correct, it's almost never a best practice.  Imagine you've started from some base image, run a lot of manual steps, and committed multiple times; and then there's a critical security update in the base image.  How can you recreate the image you have starting over from the updated base?  Pretty much the only time I'd suggest using `docker commit` at all is if you realize you've had an accident forgetting to mount a volume on to a container and are about to lose data otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

When you build an image it is immutable but if you want to modify something from an other image you can create a Dockerfile from an image that you want to modify with FROM command.

With RUN, COPY and other commands you can create your personal image.

What kind of changes do you want to do?